# What could "reject due to mismatch with WPA/WPA2" in output of wpa_supplicant mean?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, android, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to connect to an Android 4.0.4 device set up to be a wifi tether using `wpa_supplicant` with `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1

network={
    ssid="STYLUS iDroid SP 1001"
    scan_ssid=1
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=TKIP
    psk="foobar"
}
```

and this SSID and this WPA2-PSK password on the device. In the output of `wpa_supplicant` I find

```
Scan SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=21):
     53 54 59 4c 55 53 20 69 44 72 6f 69 64 20 53 50   STYLUS iDroid SP
     20 31 30 30 31                                     1001           
wlan0: Starting AP scan for specific SSID: STYLUS iDroid SP 1001
wlan0: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 1)
wlan0: Shared frequencies (len=0): completed iteration
wlan0: Add radio work 'scan'@0x1fa2c90
wlan0: First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
wlan0: Starting radio work 'scan'@0x1fa2c90 after 0.000019 second wait
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=16
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
Scan results did not fit - trying larger buffer (8192 bytes)
Received 7950 bytes of scan results (13 BSSes)
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 2
BSS: last_scan_res_used=13/32
wlan0: New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
WPS: AP[0] 50:7e:5d:3a:d6:f2 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[1] 44:94:fc:79:52:72 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[2] 08:96:d7:e1:82:77 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[3] 74:31:70:5d:fe:5c type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[4] e8:94:f6:a5:dd:3d type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[5] 34:31:c4:18:eb:a4 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[6] 88:25:2c:f5:71:76 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[7] 68:b6:fc:c3:01:e8 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[8] 68:b6:fc:d7:8d:98 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
wlan0: Radio work 'scan'@0x1fa2c90 done in 0.435438 seconds
wlan0: Selecting BSS from priority group 0
wlan0: 0: 32:aa:bd:06:39:0f ssid='STYLUS iDroid SP 1001' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-43
wlan0:    skip RSN IE - GTK cipher mismatch
wlan0:    reject due to mismatch with WPA/WPA2
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch
```

where I suspect "reject du to mismatch with WPA/WPA2" to be supposed to be an explanation what is wrong by the formulation is - as so many others - not useful and self-explanatory. How could it mean?

The connection works when I use the widget of `network-manager-gnome` (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.3) in Ubuntu 14.04 (implying the deactivation of the interface) in `/etc/network/interfaces`).

Comment: `wpa_supplicant` should be able to detect the correct values for `proto` and `key_mgmt`. Can you try after commenting out those fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out `proto`, `key_mgmt` (like suggested by @muru) and `group` and leaving them to auto detection fixed the issue (and this is probably what `network-manager-gnome` applet and/or `network-manager` do).

Answer (score 1):

According to this article no spaces in your ssid might help.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1494/wifi-wont-connect-when-ssid-has-space-character

When I saw spaces in your ssid it struck me odd so I googled whether its allowed, it is, but from what I read it can cause issues. Above  link case in point.